# Is there a way to automate Jenkins for Hg Flow/Git Flow

Tags: jenkins, mercurial, git-flow

We just switched to using Hg Flow, but one of things that we still haven't quite yet figured out is how to best use Jenkins with it. Ideally we would have a job which builds and tests develop, one that builds and tests default and other jobs which are automatically created when a feature or release branch is created, and ideally also delete the job when the feature or release is finished.

Does anyone know if this can be done, and if so, how exactly to do it?

It would be extra nice if Jenkins was able to read from Hg who it was the created the branch and mark them as the contact person if/when the job builds, but this is really just a nice to have.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Job Generator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Generator+Plugin) that could be used here. You'd create a job that watches the entire Hg repo for changes, and when it sees one, you run a task that parses the commit, and creates a new job with the new branch in place of templated fields.

If you can see a history of branch creation, you could use that information only in your job-creating task to fill out contact details too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but I found this plugin (for GitFlow):

> **[Jenkins Build Per Git Flow Branch](https://github.com/neoteric-eu/jenkins-build-per-gitflow-branch)**
>
> This script will allow you to keep your Jenkins jobs in sync with your
>   Git repository (following Git Flow branching model).

Also see the author's [blog post on this plugin](http://neoteric.eu/2015/04/make-jenkins-speak-git-flow/).